# NSLayoutConstraint programatically issue using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

I am creating UI Elements using NSlayoutconstraint programatically for the first time. But when I am implementing I am facing some problems. My issue is as follows:

If I am making buttons as per 5s device, and I want to see same as in 4s or another devices, I am not able to do it. Buttons width and height get fit with the device sizes. Buttons sizes are not increased or decreased as per the devices. Also the gaps betweens the buttons is not increased or decreased as per devices.I am not using Storyboard for this application.

Please guide me how to use and implement Scale or Multiply property inside constraints.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no way to help you without knowing the view layout and the constraints you currently have.

Comment: We need to see the constraint/s you've added, if you could post of code and  a bonus would be to show us images of what you to achieve.